# Error 'Undefined control sequence' when referencing figures or sections

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to used the command \ref{} to reference a figure (which has a label), but am receiving the error message 'Undefined control sequence', and the reference is not working. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=10cm]{ch-results/Figures/filename}
    \caption{Caption here}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure} 
Notice how cool figure \ref{fig:example} is!
```

The figure shows up fine, but the resulting line of text is:
[image]

Instead I want this to say:

[image]

For reference, the relevant part of my header is

```
\documentclass[12pt,lot, lof]{puthesis}
\newcommand{\proquestmode}{}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[skip=2pt, font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\ifdefined\printmode
\usepackage{url}
\else
\ifdefined\proquestmode
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\@title,pdfauthor=\@author}
\makeatother
\else
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, bookmarksnumbered}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\@title,pdfauthor=\@author}
\makeatother
.
.
.
\begin{document}
```

I am new to LaTeX and the majority of this is coming from a template, so I have no idea where to begin looking for the issue - I've tried googling around quite a bit, but I haven't been able to find anything that works - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try deleting the instruction `\usepackage{subfigure}` and recompiling *twice*. The `subfigure` package is incompatible with the `caption` and `subcaption` packages. (If the template you've acquired loads both packages, the template's author should hang his/her head in shame...) Moreover, `subfigure` has been deprecated for a decade or more and shouldn't be used any longer.

Comment: Or better, if possible,  dot not use templates. Start with a clean preamble and then add only what  you really need/understand. Templates are useful at first to learn about some packages and commands, and take ideas about document layouts, but they rarely can prevent you from knowing what you are doing ... and debug third templates is a pain in the ass.